# apache spark: Read large size files from a directory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I am reading each file of a directory using `wholeTextFiles`. After that I am calling a function on each element of the rdd using `map` . The whole program uses just 50 lines of each file. The code is as below:

```
def processFiles(fileNameContentsPair):
  fileName= fileNameContentsPair[0]
  result = "\n\n"+fileName
  resultEr = "\n\n"+fileName
  input = StringIO.StringIO(fileNameContentsPair[1])
  reader = csv.reader(input,strict=True)

  try:
       i=0
       for row in reader:
         if i==50:
           break
         // do some processing and get result string
         i=i+1
  except csv.Error as e:
    resultEr = resultEr +"error occured\n\n"
    return resultEr
  return result



if __name__ == "__main__":
  inputFile = sys.argv[1]
  outputFile = sys.argv[2]
  sc = SparkContext(appName = "SomeApp")
  resultRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles(inputFile).map(processFiles)
  resultRDD.saveAsTextFile(outputFile)
```

The size of each file of the directory can be very large in my case and because of this reason use of `wholeTextFiles` api will be inefficient in this case. is there any efficient way to do this ? I can think of iterating over each file of the directory one by one but that also seems to be inefficient. I am new to spark. Please let me know if there is any efficient way to do this.

Comment: how large is the size of each file? Can you not split the files to even smaller files?

Comment: @DatTran Size of each file can be in few Gbs and number of files in directory can be more than 100.  One way I can think of splitting files is splitting each file one by one and taking the first split from each file and keeping those in a temp directory. After that we can apply `wholeTextFiles` on that temp directory. is this the way you are suggesting to split the files ? If not, please let me know how would you suggest to split the files ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay what I would suggest is to split your files first into smaller chunks, a few Gbs is too large to read which is the main cause of your delay. If your data is on HDFS, you could have something like 64MB for each file. Otherwise you should experiment with the file size because it depends on the number of executors that you have. So if you have more smaller chunks, you could increase this to have more parallelism. Likewise you can also increase your partition to tune it as your `processFiles` function does not seem to be CPU intensive. The only problem with a lot of executors is that I/O increases but if file size is small that shouldn't be much of the problem.

By the way, there is no need for a temp directory, `wholeTextFiles`supports wildcards like `*`. Also note if you use S3 as a filesystem, there might be a bottleneck if you have too many small files as reading can take up a while instead of a large file. So this is not trivial.

Hope this helps!